# Makefile include

Tags: c, makefile

I apologize in advance if this is a stupid mistake, I am in my first year of studies, I will try to explain myself clearly.

Files:

```
./Makefile
./includes/my_printf.h
./sources/my_runner/test.c
```

In my `test.c` I do `#include "my_printf"`. But when I do "make" I get this as a mistake.

```
cc    -c -o analyse_events.o analyse_events.c
analyse_events.c:11:10: fatal error: my_printf.h: No such file or directory
   11 | #include "my_printf.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I've been told about "CFLAG", I've looked it up on the internet but I don't really understand how it works.
To compile I do: `gcc main.c -L sources/my_printf -lprintf -I includes`

Code Makefile:

```
NAME    = libmy_runner.a

SRC     =   strcuts/all_function.c  \
            analyse_events.c

OBJ     = $(SRC:.c=.o)

INCLUDES    =   includes/

HEADER = my_runner.h

all:    $(NAME)

$(NAME):    $(OBJ) $(INCLUDES)
    ar rc $(NAME) $(OBJ)
    cp $(HEADER) ../../includes/
    rm -f $(OBJ)

fclean:
    rm -f $(NAME)
    rm -f ../$(NAME)
    rm ../../includes/$(HEADER)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)

re: fclean all
```

Thank you for your and I hope I haven't wasted your time on a stupid mistake.

Comment: You need to add the additional include paths as an argument to gcc.

Comment: See also https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html#Invocation and search for `-iquote`

Comment: Or should I add it?

Comment: I'd recommend you do not remove any of the object files after compiling, as with that you loose the main benefit  of the Makefile

Comment: Please fix your question. You explain that you have problems compiling `test.c` but you show an error message about compiling `analyse_events.c`. And then you show a Makefile that does not match neither what you wrote. Try to be as accurate as possible and avoid typos.

Comment: According to the error message you do not add the `-I includes` flag like you wrote. Add it and it should work, maybe you need to use `-I./includes` or use `-iquote./includes`.

Comment: Is `strcuts` a typo for `structs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To indicate in which directory the header files are simply add `-I<path>` to the `CFLAGS` make variable where `<path>` is the path to the directory. Then, use the `CFLAGS` make variable in your compilation command. As there are severe mismatches between your question and the Makefile you show (all file and directory names are different), let's restart from your simple example with:

```
./Makefile
./includes/my_printf.h
./sources/my_runner/test.c
```

The following Makefile should compile your small project:

```
.PHONY: all
all: test

CFLAGS += -Iincludes

test: sources/my_runner/test.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

sources/my_runner/test.o: sources/my_runner/test.c includes/my_printf.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: `test` is a dangerous name for a program, easily confused with the `test` shell builtin.

Comment: @Jens Absolutely. I would personally not use it. But the OP does, apparently.

Comment: Thank you all for your response!

Answer (score 0):

With `#include "my_printf.h"` the preprocessor will look for a file named `my_printf.h` in the folder in which you are compiling, you need to add the full path to it to include properly:

```
#include "../../includes/my_printf.h"
```

Comment: It works, but I thought it was possible to do it directly in the Makefile, thank you for your answer.

Comment: It is not about the makefile here, it's about the compiler having access to the header. You can make all sorts of hacks to copy the header with the makefile but in the end the compiled file needs to know where the header is located